# Android Cling (DLNA) AVTransport

Tags: android, dlna, cling

I have a problem when using Cling to stream image to TV that I can stream image to my TV but the image size not is full screen.  How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your TV works as a DLNA renderer and the renderer determines how image is displayed. Therefore, you should check the specification of the TV.